# Defining a symbol in a header whose repeated instances will be merged by the linker

Tags: c, linker

Is there any way in C, to *define* a symbol such that all indentical *definitions* will be merged by the linker? It seems possible at the linker level since, for example, C++ supports template functions and template static variables that do exactly this<sup>1</sup>.

To be concrete, let's say I want to define an `int array[]` like this, in a header file `int_array.h`:

```
int array[42] = {};
```

and when many separate compilation units all include `int_array.h`, their corresponding `.o` files will evidently include the definition and space for `array` - but when they are linked together, I want that only one `array` symbol survives and everyone points to it.

The answer doesn't have to be *standard C* (indeed, the linker isn't really explicitly addressed by the standard) - but it should be generally applicable to modern compilers.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a C question, not a C++ one, but as it turns out every modern toolchain uses the same linker for both.

Comment: You can declare your symbol as many times as you like so long as all the declarations are the same. You appear to be asking if you can define it (by initialising it) multiple times, in which case, AFAIK, no you can't.

Comment: @IanMiller - exactly. I tried to be careful to use _declare_ rather than _define_ when asking my question, and apparently my attention span was pretty much the question title and nothing else. Should be fixed now.

Comment: If you define the array in the header and include the header in multiple files, doesn't the linker complain, that the array is defined mutiple times?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare them as weak:

```
__attribute__((weak)) int array[42] = {};
```

For more info see e.g. [here](https://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2008/gcc-weak-symbols/).